# Movie with a crane smashing into an apartment building, a father looking for his son, and a computer/AI that watches everything through cameras

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to find a movie I watched about 10 years ago, I don’t remember much of the plot, nor the title, and I’m trying to figure it out.

I recall the following details:

- Crane smashes into apartment building.
- Father is trying to find his son.
- Based in New York maybe?
- (Sphere like?) computer/AI has multiple surveillance cameras and watches everything.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did the movie look like it was made in the 2000s, or did it look older than that?

Comment: hi, thank you, yes it looked like early 2000s or late 90s I believe

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark but the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Or you can [edit] more details in.

Answer (score 10):

You may be thinking of the 2008 film *[Eagle Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Eye*)*. It has a man and a woman being manipulated by the AI, with the woman trying to save her son, but otherwise it matches.

> In January 2009, Stanford University dropout Jerry Shaw learns that his identical twin brother Ethan, an officer in the U.S. Air Force, has been killed. Following the funeral, Jerry is surprised to find $750,000 in his bank account and his apartment filled with illicit items. He receives a phone call from a woman who warns that the FBI is about to arrest him and he needs to run. Jerry is caught by the FBI and interrogated by Supervising Agent Tom Morgan.
>
> While Morgan confers with Air Force OSI Special Agent Zoe Pérez, the woman on the phone arranges for Jerry's escape and directs him to Rachel Holloman, a single mother. The woman on the phone is coercing Rachel by threatening her son Sam, who is aboard the Capitol Limited en route to the Kennedy Center in Washington, D.C. with his school band. The woman on the phone helps the two avoid law enforcement by controlling networked devices, including traffic lights, mobile phones, automated cranes, and even power lines....

### Trailer

### The scene with the crane

Comment: thank you both so much! this is it :)

Answer (score 5):

Could be *[Eagle Eye](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1059786/)*. Made in 2008 which fits. The computer (ARIIA) is a black sphere, and can tap into any networked camera, phone, or other device to observe the protagonists or take action. The plot summary mentions it using a crane, although I don't recall the specific scene.

The female FBI agent (Rrachel Monaghan) has a son - finding him is a plot point - and she spends most of the movie with the male lead (Shia LeBeouf), so possible you misremember who the parent was.

Comment: thank you both so much! this is it :)